# How to save the configurations made in Guest session?

Tags: configuration, guest-session

I have a desktop installed Ubuntu 13.10. And I can save every changes I make in my account. But I did so much things like clicking `remember me later` in updates, or Something like that in the guest session.But I couldn't save it, I mean it won't be saved even If I clicked it once.

For example; I can't even save the desktop background I mean.

And I want to make it savable. And I want to make the guest session files savable and work as we do in default account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want would defeat the purpose with [the guest session feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html). What you can do is [customizing the guest session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) in advance, but anything you do from within a guest session will be deleted when you log out.

Comment: But can't i make it save those settings at least with getting into root directories?

Comment: @NivedKannada: You can't act as root within a guest session. Using the method described in the second page I linked to, you can save whatever you like, but only in advance. Maybe you really want a second regular user account, as Paulocoghi suggested in the other answer?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the most valid approach would be to create a new account only for this purpose, for "guest" users that aren't normal users for you.

Choose a name that is valid for you in this purpose (like `visitor`), set it to login without password, and you are in!